# need to reset dirty bit on usb flash memory stick

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, mount, usb-flash-drive

We have a usb memory stick that FreeBSD-11 will not mount because its file system is not clean.  It is not clean because it was removed from an extension cable while it was mounted on a FreeBSD-11 system.  However, there was no file activity that we are aware of at the time it was removed.

We cannot get `fsck` or `fsck_ffs` to find a superblock so these will not run.  Even when we provide `fsck_ffs -b` with a superblock address found using `newfs -N` it does not consider the block location as a superblock.

How do we clear the dirty bit so that we can mount the device?

Comment: What filesystem is the flash drive? UFS? Ext*? Other?

Comment: file system is `linux-data`

Comment: ^ That's a partition ID, not a filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was repaired with: `fsck.ext3 /dev/da0s1`